# Compute the probability of an event if dependent events occur together

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Probability of winning a game of soccer, given 1 of the 10 players is Messi, is = 0.8.
Probability of winning the same game, given 1 of the 10 players is Ronaldo is = 0.6.
What is the probability of winning if both Ronaldo and Messi are in the team?

So, using notations -

```
Given,
P(Win | Messi playing) = 0.8 and 
P(Win | Ronaldo playing) = 0.6

What is P(Win | both playing)?
```

Initially I thought solving it in this way -

```
Prob of losing with Messi = 1 - 0.8 = 0.2
Prob of losing with Ronaldo = 1 - 0.6 = 0.4
Prob. of losing if both Messi and Ronaldo is = 0.2 X 0.4 = 0.08
So, P(win| Ronaldo & Messi) = 1 - 0.08 = 0.92
```

But this clearly does not seem right.  Can someone please help me here?

*(I do not have any formal training in mathematics other than what I learnt 20 over years ago in high school, some direction will be greatly appreciated)*

**EDIT**

Here is another version of the problem -

*Probability of rain is 0.8 if temperature drops more than 5 degree. Probability of rain is 0.6 if pressure drops 10%. What is the probability of rain if temperature drops more than 5 and pressure drops 10%? Assume temperature drop and pressure drops are independent events.*

Comment: This isn't really a probability question.  After all, don't you imagine it possible that Ronaldo and Messi have such extreme egos that their presence on the same team would virtually guarantee a *loss*?

Comment: my :facepalm moment!

Comment: To be honest, the original question was something like this - Probability of rain is 0.8 if temperature drops more than 5 degree. Probability of rain is 0.6 if pressure drops 10%. What is the probability of rain if temperature drops more than 5 and pressure drops 10%.

I asked it in another way.

Comment: Your analogy remains a good one, though.  For instance, a simultaneous drop in temperature and pressure could (conceivably, absent any knowledge of meteorology) guarantee rain or just as plausibly guarantee the absence of rain.  The independence of changes in temperature and pressure doesn't help narrow the range of mathematically possible answers.